# $@ in alias inside script: is there a "local" $@?

Tags: bash, alias, function, pushd

I have aliased `pushd` in my bash shell as follows so that it suppresses output:

```
alias pushd='pushd "$@" > /dev/null'
```

This works fine most of the time, but I'm running into trouble now using it inside functions that take arguments. For example,

```
test() {
  pushd .
  ...
}
```

Running `test` without arguments is fine. But with arguments:

```
> test x y z
bash: pushd: too many arguments
```

I take it that `pushd` is trying to take `. x y z` as arguments instead of just `.`. How can I prevent this? Is there a "local" equivalent of `$@` that would only see `.` and not `x y z`?

Comment: Why are you using `$@` at all?

Comment: @Wildcard Because I had copy/pasted that line from someone else who was apparently also a beginner like me. :S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aliases define a way to replace a shell token with some string before the shell event tries to parse code. It's not a programming structure like a function.

In

```
alias pushd='pushd "$@" > /dev/null'
```

and then:

```
pushd .
```

What's going on is that the `pushd` is replaced with `pushd "$@" > /dev/null` and then the result parsed. So the shell ends up parsing:

```
pushd "$@" > /dev/null .
```

Redirections can appear anywhere on the command line, so it's exactly the same as:

```
pushd "$@" . > /dev/null
```

or

```
> /dev/null pushd "$@" .
```

When you're running that from the prompt, `"$@"` is the list of arguments your shell received so unless you ran `set arg1 arg2`, that will likely be empty, so it will be the same as

```
pushd . > /dev/null
```

But within a function, that `"$@"` will be the arguments of the function.

Here, you either want to define `pushd` as a function like:

```
pushd() { command pushd "$@" > /dev/null; }
```

Or an alias like:

```
alias pushd='> /dev/null pushd'
```

or

```
alias pushd='pushd > /dev/null
```

Comment: I had actually thought of writing it as a function, but I didn't know about `command` yet, so of course it created an infinite loop.